# Using bootstrap to go from 3x2(desktop) to 2x3 (mobile) layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

My webpage in desktop view is divided into a 2x3 layout i.e two rows with 3 grid-columns each (bootstrap rows and columns), as given in below:

```
**image1   image2   image3
image4   image5   image6**

<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      <img src="image1.png"/>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      <img src="image2.png"/>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      <img src="image3.png"/>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      <img src="image4.png"/>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      <img src="image5.png"/>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      <img src="image6.png"/>
   </div>
</div>
```

When I reduce to a mobile size(col-xs), I want the page two be in a 2x3 layout, as given below:

```
**image1   image2
image3   image4
image5   image6**
```

Can this be achieved using the bootstrap framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the declaration for the xs viewport in your column classes and make it a single row, like you see below. As long as the columns (and column offsets if you're using them) equal to 12, you can use a single row wrapper to make several rows worth of columns. I'm glad I could help.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
         <img src="image1.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <img src="image2.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <img src="image3.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <img src="image4.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <img src="image5.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <img src="image6.png"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Example:
http://www.bootply.com/8JlDo3kXKH

Comment: Great! That works! Thanks. I didn't realize you can put all of them in one row

Comment: I updated my answer to include that distinction about the rows and columns. I'm glad I could help.